# How to extract a dynamic bunch of words between two patterns using regex

Tags: regex

I've been trying to extract a (dynamic) bunch of words from an invoice. As this is the product description, it changes for each invoice. I tried to use the productnumber and a lookbehind, but that wouldn't always work, because there are other 6-8digitnumbers in the same invoice, is there a way to set the 6-8digitnumber and the date ahead also as a reference?

```
Description Productnumber Delivery Amount VAT Price excl. Price incl. Value excl. Value incl.
BenQ XL2430T (24", 1920 x 1080 Pixels) 2774800 21.11.2014 1 8.00% 323.15 349.00 323.15 349.00
LG Nexus 5X (32GB, Quarz, 5.20", Single SIM, 12.30Mpx, 4G) 5636609 03.03.2016 1 8.00% 276.85 299.00 276.85 299.00
```

So what I'd want to extract in this case is

1. BenQ XL2430T (24", 1920 x 1080 Pixels)
2. LG Nexus 5X (32GB, Quarz, 5.20", Single SIM, 12.30Mpx, 4G)

Is this even possible or am I trying the impossible?

As for code so far I extract the product number with:

```
\b\d{6,7}(?=\s+(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\.[12]\d{3})
```

but I just can't get around to include that in a lookahaed of the productnumber...

(that also only gives me the first result and I'd need the second product code extracted as well)

Hopefully this is understandable and it'd be much appreciated of somebody could help.

- cheers

Comment: What flavor of regex are you using ?

Comment: `^[\w\s(?,".]+\)?\s(?=[\d]{6,8})` - Does this work for you ? https://regex101.com/r/HBvG3K/4

Comment: @rootkonda 
silly me.. I'm using the .net framework, it's for an rpa task in uipath :)
well it is working, but only kinda, it also matches anything before the product description... :(

Comment: Every line starts with description isnt it ? If you checked the link I mentioned in earlier comment. I only used the two rows from the example u provided. I assume the header values will not be passed to regex ??

Comment: I might have explained myself wrong, regex will be processed through the whole invoice including the row above. However, I could make a workaround splitting the pdf and only handover the specific part, but that would also be more time-consuming in the end. That's why I was hoping I'd get the "perfect" solution :P

Comment: We can ignore the first row like this https://regex101.com/r/HBvG3K/5

Comment: Nice, this kind of works - is there a way to ignore everything that is above too? Thanks alot for your help so far, much appreciated.

Comment: That's what the regex is doing to ignore and it only captures the required part. I will post this as an answer for you to accept it.

Comment: Well but if there's text infront of the headers it won't work: check https://regex101.com/r/HBvG3K/12

Comment: I am checking it

Comment: Does the product format always the same for all products ? always description has brackets ?? You can check this example  - https://regex101.com/r/HBvG3K/14 Check against your examples and let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!Description Productnumber)[\w\s(?,".]+\)?\s(?=[\d]{6,8})
```

Demo and explanation on syntax of the regex used:

https://regex101.com/r/HBvG3K/5